# Differences between Thread.sleep() and TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()

Tags: java

What is the difference between Thread.sleep() and TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()?
Thanks,any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference (except that Thread#sleep takes a millisecond amount).

> ([TimeUnit#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep%28long%29)) is a convenience method that converts time arguments into the form required by the Thread.sleep method.